# AWS describe-network-interfaces behavior when filtered by list of security groups & list of interface Ids

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, boto3

I am slightly confused with the way the following would function:

```
profile_session = boto3.session.Session(aws_access_key_id=accessKey,aws_secret_access_key=acc
essSecret,region_name=awsRegion)
ec2_client = profile_session.client('ec2')
describeNetworkInterfacesResponse = ec2_client.describe_network_interfaces(Filters=[{'Name':'group-id', 'Values':listOfGroupIds if type(listOfGroupIds) == list else [listOfGroupIds]}, {'Name':'network-interface-id', 'Values':listOfinterfaceIds}])
```

Given that the `len(listOfGroupIds)` is **145** and that the `len(listOfinterfaceIds)` is **40** & that `ec2_client` is the EC2 when I run the above, I get the following as the value of `describeNetworkInterfacesResponse`

```
{'NetworkInterfaces': [],
 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '6b52c532-f582-4607-8c3c-8366441dbc11',
  'HTTPStatusCode': 200,
  'HTTPHeaders': {'content-type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8',
   'content-length': '251',
   'date': 'Sun, 20 Oct 2019 11:20:37 GMT',
   'server': 'AmazonEC2'},
  'RetryAttempts': 0}}
```

Is my understanding correct that `ec2_client.describe_network_interfaces`, with those filters, would check for **every single network interface id** in the list *listOfinterfaceIds* for **any single, or combination of,  security groups**, from the *listOfGroupIds*, attached to the interface & return the details of that network interface ?

Since the response, `describeNetworkInterfacesResponse` did not really have any network interfaces returned, I am a little skeptical if I am understanding it right.

Put the other way round, and considering that `listOfGroupIds` is a list of security group ids and that `listOfInterfaceId` is a list of network interface ids, will the below 4 code snippets yield the same results (minus the print statement of course)?

*snippet 1*

```
describeNetworkInterfacesResponse = ec2_client.describe_network_interfaces(Filters=[{'Name':'group-id', 'Values':listOfGroupIds if type(listOfGroupIds) == list else [listOfGroupIds]}, {'Name':'network-interface-id', 'Values':listOfInterfaceId}])
```

*snippet 2*

```
for netId in listOfInterfaceId:
    print("Processing {0}".format(str(netId)))
    describeNetworkInterfacesResponse = ec2_client.describe_network_interfaces(Filters=[{'Name':'group-id', 'Values':listOfGroupIds if type(listOfGroupIds) == list else [listOfGroupIds]}, {'Name':'network-interface-id', 'Values':[netId]}])
    if describeNetworkInterfacesResponse.get('NetworkInterfaces'):
      print(describeNetworkInterfacesResponse)
```

*snippet 3*

```
for groupId in listOfGroupIds:
    print("Processing {0}".format(str(netId)))
    describeNetworkInterfacesResponse = ec2_client.describe_network_interfaces(Filters=[{'Name':'group-id', 'Values':groupId if type(groupId) == list else [groupId]}, {'Name':'network-interface-id', 'Values':[listOfInterfaceIds]}])
    if describeNetworkInterfacesResponse.get('NetworkInterfaces'):
      print(describeNetworkInterfacesResponse)
```

*snippet 4*

```
for groupId in listOfGroupIds:
    print("\n[*] For security group  {0}".format(str(groupId)))
    for netId in listOfInterfaceIds:
        print("[+] Processing interface {0}".format(str(netId)))
        describeNetworkInterfacesResponse = ec2_client.describe_network_interfaces(Filters=[{'Name':'group-id', 'Values':groupId if type(groupId) == list else [groupId]}, {'Name':'network-interface-id', 'Values':[netId]}])
        if describeNetworkInterfacesResponse.get('NetworkInterfaces'):
          print(describeNetworkInterfacesResponse)
```

And which of the above 4 is the most performant way of doing it? (The 4th snippet is definitely the worst, as it visibly takes way more than any other snippet to finish off, but without clarity on the confusion expressed above in this question, *snippet 4* alone seems to be a guaranteed way of fetching the needed information.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I did figure out the answer. All the 4 code snippets gave the exact same response. Below is the time taken for each to get completed:

*Snippet 1* took:

> --- 3.737805128097534 seconds ---

*Snippet 2:* took (given that the matching interface id  was last on the list of interface ids:

> --- 134.37576508522034 seconds ---

*Snippet 3:* took:

> --- 414.51906514167786 seconds ---

*Snippet 4:* Did not bother running it at all.